# Include Pod creation time in Kubernetes Pod name

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is it possible to specify the Pod creation time as part of the k8s Pod Name?

**Scenario:**
I have many pods with the same name prefix (and uniquely generated tail-end of the name) and these are all names of log groups.

I wish to distinguish between log groups by creation time.

Unfortunately AWS CloudWatch Logs console does not sort by log group creation time.

Comment: And how do you currently fill in "uniquely generated tail-end of the name"? Do you use deplyoment so it is k8s generated for you or you crate pod manifests directly and create this yourself?

Comment: i used a Deployment so its generated. It flows to CloudWatch through fluentd DaemonSet in the cluster

Answer (score 2):

No, not with a deployment at least, a stateful set would work but you should really be using labels here.