# How to get Pod creation time in pod spec yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to get timestamp using downward API or any other way in pod spec

Checked here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api, but couldn't find timestamp.

Below is sample section from yaml where  i want to generate output file with timestamp.

```
          args:
            - "audit"
            - "--config"
            - "/opt/app/app-config/app.yaml"
            - "--format"
            - "json"
            - "--output-file"
            - "/var/log/app/app-$(date +%s).log"
```

Similar questions:

- [Include Pod creation time in Kubernetes Pod name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218081/include-pod-creation-time-in-kubernetes-pod-name)
- [Include Pod creation time in Kubernetes Pod name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218081/include-pod-creation-time-in-kubernetes-pod-name)

Comment: You can wrap this in a `sh -c` invocation to cause a shell to do the subprocess expansion.

Comment: thanks for response  and helpful answer @DavidMaze, these options are in my mind, but was looking if there are some native k8s options.

Comment: Could you try with `kubectl set env deployment/deployment-name TIMESTAMP=$(kubectl get pod pod-name -o jsonpath='{.metadata.creationTimestamp}')`? This will set creationTimestamp value as the env variable with TIMESTAMP name. You can check the results with `kubectl describe pod pod-name` and search for Environment. Additionally you can use `kubectl -n namespace get pod pod_name -o jsonpath="{range .status.conditions[*]}{.type}{','}{.lastTransitionTime}{'\n'}{end}"` to get all the events of the pod with timestamps. Let me know if that answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments by @David Maze

> You can wrap this in a sh -c invocation to cause a shell to do the subprocess expansion.

---

Other way here would be to use [kubectl set](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#set).

You can use

```
kubectl set env deployment/deployment-name TIMESTAMP=$(kubectl get pod pod-name -o jsonpath='{.metadata.creationTimestamp}')
```

This will set creationTimestamp value as the env variable with TIMESTAMP name.

You can check the results with `kubectl describe pod pod-name` and search for Environment.

---

Additionally you can use

```
kubectl -n namespace get pod pod_name -o jsonpath="{range .status.conditions[*]}{.type}{','}{.lastTransitionTime}{'\n'}{end}"
```

to get all the events of the pod with timestamps

Comment: was working on something similar and this gave me the idea of using label instead ```kubectl label -f deploy.yaml deployid=123``` then I can get the pods using ```kubectl get pods -l deployid=123```